# Create a label from label string to int

Tags: objective-c, string, math, label

Hello I am a beginner programmer and am making a math game app.

I have a check answer button and I am doing a if statement like

```
if textbox= label1.text + label2.text
```

then

```
label3.text = correct
```

The part I'm confused on is how would I convert label from string to int because the label is a string so it can't add I will need to make it a int variable which equals the label so that they can add and check if the user enters the correct answer.

Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: @La-comadreja it is objective c in xcode.

Comment: Most likely you have to apply a function called atoi (ascii to integer, in C) or parseInt or something similar to all of the strings. Also take care that comparison is the == sign, a single = is always an assignment.

Comment: How about if I do int num = ([label.text integervalue]); to convert label to a int so I can add them

Answer (score 0):

In objective c the correct way to do this for ios would be:

```
    if ([label1.text intValue] + [label2.text intValue] == [textbox intValue]) {
        [label3 setText:@"Correct!"];
    }
```

however if you are developing for OS X (where you use NSLabel) replace [label1.text intValue] with [label1 integerValue].

Comment: the labels work fine but i am getting a error with the text box i declared it as uitextfield and named it sum but the code has a error.

Comment: if ([label.text intValue] + [label1.text intValue] == [sum])   {
        [label3 setText:@"Correct!"];
    }

Comment: but it says expected identifier

Comment: you need to type [sum intValue] not [sum]